# Why pass dot (.) separated string to "p"?

Tags: ruby

I'm working on some ERB templates that are not my own, and I see the developer has used statements like this a lot:

`<%= p("object.property.foo") %>`

Where *object* is an *OpenStruct*. This method call results in the value of `object.property.foo` being printed (as in JavaScript, or most languages I know). Which is awesome because it is much more simple than writing:

`<%= object["property"]["foo"] %>`

My questions are:

- Why am I able to access properties with "." notation?
- Why do I pass a string to `p` and not the object itself?
- Why is `p` preferable in this case? (I know `p` vs. `puts`, but why use `p` here?)

Comment: This is pretty much the whole point of OpenStruct. [Check out the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html)

Comment: Yikes, I was misdirected! Haha, if you want to put that as an answer I'll take it. But also, it's curious to me why I'm passing a string into `p` and not the object reference itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `<%=    %>` tells the ERB parser to evaluate the content as a ruby expression, and to include the return value in the resulting HTML text.
- `p(    )` is likely to be a view helper function that creates some HTML tags. This is not obvious from the code fragment. Apparently it evaluates the string argument, again as another ruby expression. `p` is not a standard rails or ruby method.
- `object` is according to the questioner an OpenStruct. `OpenStruct` is a data structure that combines the behaviour of a Hash with the syntax of class methods. It is documented here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html
- `object.property` asks OpenStruct to apply `property` on `object`. OpenStruct replies with a stored value, something like `@value[property]`, where `@value` would be a Hash. You do not need square bracket syntax, because OpenStruct provides dynamic access methods. The '.' is the ruby operator to apply a method to an object. The internal implementation of OpenStruct's data storage does not have be be a Hash at all. According to the questioner, the return value is another instance of OpenStruct.
- `object.property.foo` calls method `foo` on the instance of OpenStruct that was returned from `object.property`. Now we receive the value of a nested OpenStruct object structure.

Comment: Could you explain why this is important? How does it answer my questions? Maybe an example.

Comment: @Breedly Two open questions remaining: (a) what does :p do, and (b) can you confirm if both `object` and `object.property` are instances of OpenStruct? Can you inspect with `pry`?

Comment: Both are open struct.

Comment: @Breedly can you check `show-method p ` at the location in pry, or replace `<%= p("object.property.foo") %>` with `<%= method(:p) %>` and see what you get in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the developer may have aliased the `eval` statement with `p` somewhere earlier in the code.

```
require 'ostruct'
o = OpenStruct.new(key: 5)
o.key  # returns 5

alias p eval
p("o.key")  # returns 5
```

`eval` is simply a function that executes any string passed into it as ruby code.

Regarding your question

> Why is p preferable in this case? (I know p vs. puts, but why use p here?)

I don't believe you are using the classic `p` function here. By default that `p` does not "eval" strings passed into it. The `p` function must have been overwritten with the `eval` function. Check the code base for something like `alias p eval` or `alias_method :p, :eval`

Comment: That would be a pointless alias, because the ERB parser is evaluating the ruby statement be default.